# Using shift() brings back the first one every time (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that searches for every time `;` is found inside a textarea and makes it into a array. See the code below.

```
function compile() {
    // Sets the variable for every line
    var compileLineCount = document.getElementById('devInput').value.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < compileLineCount.length; i++) {
        console.log(document.getElementById('devInput').value.split(';').shift(i))
        console.log(i)
    }
}
```

But whenever I call the function, it shows the first one every time.

[image: screenshot of console log when I run the function]

Anyone know how to fix this? Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please check [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) for what `.shift()` is expected to do. Please read: **`The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that removed element.`** Please see if that information helps to resolve the issue faced.

Comment: What do you want to do? Shift doesn't accept parameters and will always return the first value of the array, also it deletes that value mutating the array in the process

Answer (score 1):

As per the official [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) document.

*The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that removed element. This method changes the length of the array.*

Hence, It should be like **:**

```js
var compileLineCount = document.getElementById('devInput').innerHTML.split(';');
for (let i = 0; i <= compileLineCount.length; i++) {
  const splittedValue = compileLineCount.shift(i)
  console.log(splittedValue)
  console.log(i)
}
```

```html
<p id="devInput">
Hello my name is alpha;Age is 30;I love to help
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I did wrong. I forgot shift() also removes the item from the array.

I changed it from .shift(i) to [i].

Thank you [jsn00b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13658816/jsn00b) for the link to the docs

Answer (score 0):

Your `shift()` method is used incorrectly. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift), it states:

> The `shift()` method removes the **first** element from an array and returns that removed element.

So, the `shift()` method doesn't take any parameters. This is why your code isn't working.

---

To fix this issue, you can get the index from the array using `[i]`, like so.

```js
document.getElementById("devInput").value.split(";")[i];
```

The only difference in that line is that `.shift()` is replaced with `[i]`, which gets the element in the array at that specific index.